# Mongo how to get specific array field with value or object value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have these mongo fields

```
    "username" : "aaaaaa",
    "emails" : [
               {
                   "address" : "a@yahoo.comm",
                   "verified" : false
               }
               ],
    "profile" : {
                   "firstname" : "a",
                   "lastname" : "a"
                }
```

I can do

```
db.users.find({username:'aaaaaa'});
```

My question is, how about if I want to use the email address or profile's firstname?

It seems like this

```
db.users.find({email:{firstname:'a@yahoo.com'}});
```

but it doesn't work. and I can't use

```
email['address']:'a@yahoo.com'
```

or even

```
profile:{firstname:'a'} // profile.firstname:'a';
```

How can I get only their value?

Comment: Try db.users.find({'email.firstname':'a@yahoo.com'});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the email address to query then,

```
db.users.find({'emails.address':'a@yahoo.com'});
```

If you want to use the profile's firstname to query,

```
db.users.find({'profile.firstname':'a'});
```

Comment: Actually, you'll want `find({'emails.0.address': 'foo'});` -- note the `0` between `emails` and `address`. This is because `emails` is an array.